# Create new view for Account Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

I'm Trying to implement a Email Activation action.

I successfully added Action to Controller and it get called when I access the URL:
/Account/EmailActivation

AlsoCreated the corresponding View file as /Views/Account/EmailActivation.cshtml.

But, when app start to render, the main _ViewStart.cshtml is used instead of 
/Views/Account/_ViewStart.cshtml.

It causes app to raise errors.

What I'm missing?

```
#AccountController 
public class AccountController : cadastroControllerBase
{
    ...

    public ActionResult EmailActivation()
    {
        return View("EmailActivation");
    }
```

**OBS: I'm using ABP (ASP.NET Boilerplate) with ASP.NET MVC 5 & jQuery**

Comment: Its `_ViewStart.cshtml`, (not `_View_Start`)

Comment: Yep, just a Typo.

Comment: Show how you `return` in `EmailActivation` action.

Comment: All parent `_ViewStart.cshtml` are called. Did you override `Layout` in `Account/_ViewStart.cshtml` or what is not working?

Comment: Yes, all parent `_ViewStart.cshtml` was called. Just changed the return to code below and worked fine. Maybe this overload form was not intercepted somewhere in ABP code.

Comment: You didn't pass in your model. That has nothing to do with interception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

After changing the return of EmailActivation action as below, everything worked as expected:

```
public ActionResult EmailActivation()
{
    ViewBag.IsMultiTenancyEnabled = _multiTenancyConfig.IsEnabled;

    return View("EmailActivation", 
            new EmailActivationFormViewModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = Request.ApplicationPath,
                IsMultiTenancyEnabled = _multiTenancyConfig.IsEnabled,
                IsSelfRegistrationAllowed = IsSelfRegistrationEnabled(),
                MultiTenancySide = AbpSession.MultiTenancySide
            });
}
```